# How to encrypt chat application in java?

Tags: java, encryption, rsa

I'm trying to write a chat program with RSA encryption in Java. I found RSA class:

```
public class RSA {

private BigInteger n, d, e;

private int bits = 1024;

/** Create an instance that can encrypt using someone elses public key. */
public RSA(BigInteger newn, BigInteger newe) {
    n = newn;
    e = newe;
}

/** Create an instance that can both encrypt and decrypt. */
public RSA(int bits) {
    this.bits = bits;
    SecureRandom r = new SecureRandom();
    BigInteger p = new BigInteger(this.bits / 2, 100, r);
    BigInteger q = new BigInteger(this.bits / 2, 100, r);
    n = p.multiply(q);
    BigInteger m = (p.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)).multiply(q
        .subtract(BigInteger.ONE));
    e = new BigInteger("3");
    while (m.gcd(e).intValue() > 1) {
        e = e.add(new BigInteger("2"));
    }
    d = e.modInverse(m);
}

/** Encrypt the given plaintext message. */
public synchronized String encrypt(String message) {
    return (new BigInteger(message.getBytes())).modPow(e, n).toString();
}

/** Encrypt the given plaintext message. */
public synchronized BigInteger encrypt(BigInteger message) {
    return message.modPow(e, n);
}

/** Decrypt the given ciphertext message. */
public synchronized String decrypt(String message) {
    return new String((new BigInteger(message)).modPow(d, n).toByteArray());
}

/** Decrypt the given ciphertext message. */
public synchronized BigInteger decrypt(BigInteger message) {
    return message.modPow(d, n);
}

/** Generate a new public and private key set. */
public synchronized void generateKeys() {
    SecureRandom r = new SecureRandom();
    BigInteger p = new BigInteger(bits / 2, 100, r);
    BigInteger q = new BigInteger(bits / 2, 100, r);
    n = p.multiply(q);
    BigInteger m = (p.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)).multiply(q
        .subtract(BigInteger.ONE));
    e = new BigInteger("3");
    while (m.gcd(e).intValue() > 1) {
        e = e.add(new BigInteger("2"));
    }
    d = e.modInverse(m);
}

/** Return the modulus. */
public synchronized BigInteger getN() {
    return n;
}

/** Return the public key. */
public synchronized BigInteger getE() {
    return e;
}
}
```

When server starts it creates own RSA object:

```
public static RSA ownRsa = new RSA(1024);
```

So, after that I created 2 methods for clients:

```
public static BigInteger getServersN() {
    return ownRsa.getN();
}


public static BigInteger getServersE() {
    return ownRsa.getE();
}
```

When client starts, it also creates his own RSA object, also he creates another rsa object with server's public key:

```
public static RSA ownRsa = new RSA(1024);
public static RSA rsa = new RSA(ServerAction.getServersN(), ServerAction.getServersE());
```

So when client sends message it will be encrypted with server's public key(N and E). When message arrives to server I can decrypt it. But how can I encrypt message on server to send it to another clients? As I understood I need to send public keys from each client to server but then I have to encrypt lots of messages and keep all public keys. Maybe my logic completely wrong or I don't get something. Can anyone give any advice? Thank you.

Comment: No, you're correct. You have to know every client's public keys. But computers usually don't care. A key is just a few bytes.

Comment: Please don't do this. RSA is a primitive operation from which experts can build encryption schemes, not an encryption scheme. If you're going to go this route, you have to understand a lot of things that it doesn't seem like you're ready to deal with such as chaining modes, padding, and so on. If you're looking for transport encryption, you want something like SSL.

Comment: if this is for your own educational purpose, i.e. no real world application (in which case i'd strongly recommend using TLS) you might want to think about having a symetric cipher like AES with one key per chat group (which needs to be changed when someone enters or leaves a group) and exchanging those keys using RSA

Comment: Java has RSA encryption/decryption and key generation included. This includes secure padding modes such as OAEP, which can be used as a building block for a hybrid cryptosystem.